# f2py intel compiler blas

Tags: intel, f2py

I am on windows machine I am trying to compile a fortran subroutine that has call out to some blas function.  I have not seen any examples of how to compile the module using Windows and intel compiler with mkl.

Any pointers on where to start will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the Intel compiler? Otherwise you can use OpenBLAS instead.

Comment: Yes. I have access to intel compilers and was wondering what the procedure would be to link to the mkl blas libraries through f2py.